# jq - create empty array and add objects to it

Tags: bash, jq

I am working on a bash script (using jq for JSON parsing)

1. that needs to make multiple CURL calls (response has same structure but different values), apply some logic/filters and then collate all the responses in one final JSON array of objects.
2. Loop through this final JSON array and write into a CSV in a predefined format.

Searched for a bit for both the requirements but could not find anything concrete. Please advice. The highlighted steps below (in ***) are the points where I need help.

**Sample Flow :**

```
create empty FINAL array

for(eachService is serviceList)
       a. CURL <service_response> returning JSON array of objects
       b. use jq filters to parse JSON response, apply some logic and modify elements in response as needed
       c. ***add this JSON array to FINAL array***

***LOOP through FINAL array, one object at a time a write to CSV.***
```

**Sample Data :**

```
CURL Response 1 (ex: $curl1):
[
  {
    "id":"123",
    "startDate": "2016-12-09T00:00:00Z",
    "calls":4
  },
  {
    "id":"456",
    "startDate": "2016-12-09T00:00:00Z",
    "calls":22
  }
]

CURL Response 2 (ex : $curl2): 
[
  {
    "id":"789",
    "startDate": "2016-12-09T00:00:00Z",
    "calls":8
  },
  {
    "id":"147",
    "startDate": "2016-12-09T00:00:00Z",
    "calls":10
  }
]

NEEDED OUTPUT ($final): 
[
{
    "id":"123",
    "startDate": "2016-12-09T00:00:00Z",
    "calls":4
  },
  {
    "id":"456",
    "startDate": "2016-12-09T00:00:00Z",
    "calls":22
  },
  {
    "id":"789",
    "startDate": "2016-12-09T00:00:00Z",
    "calls":8
  },
  {
    "id":"147",
    "startDate": "2016-12-09T00:00:00Z",
    "calls":10
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jq` can deal with multiple input arrays. You can pipe the whole output of the loop to it:

```
for service in "$services" ; do
    curl "$service/path"
done | jq -r '.[]|[.id,.startDate,.calls]|@csv'
```

Note that the csv transformation can be done by `@csv`

Comment: Is it possible to also sort the rows from across the calls ? For example, I'd want the CSV rows to be sorted on the descending order of 'calls' value. Thanks

Comment: Pipe it to `| sort -t',' k3,3nr`

Answer (score 2):

As @hek2mlg pointed out, it should be possible to invoke jq just once. If the input is sufficiently uniform (admittedly, maybe a big "if"), you could even avoid having to name the fields explicitly, e.g.:

```
$ for service in "$services" ; do
    curl "$service/path"
  done | jq -sr 'add[] | [.[]] | @csv'
```

Output:

```
"123","2016-12-09T00:00:00Z",4
"456","2016-12-09T00:00:00Z",22
"789","2016-12-09T00:00:00Z",8
"147","2016-12-09T00:00:00Z",10
```

Note that using -s allows you to perform arbitrary computations on all the inputs, e.g. counting them.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a "final" array. You can process the individual JSON output of each `curl` call, and parse each with the same `jq` script, converting JSON input to CSV output. Something along the lines of:

```
for url; do
    curl "$url" | jq 'filter-and-extract-csv-columns'
done > output.csv
```

Notice the redirection of the entire loop to `output.csv`.

This kind of streamlined processing is possible thanks to the CVS format being flat without a surrounding context as in XML or JSON. The output of multiple computations can be simply concatenated.

Comment: also need to address the requirement of data transformation (add/modify) before writing to CSV. Was hence trying to do it JSON and jq.

Comment: Well yes, do all the necessary data transformations in `jq`, and then output in CSV. You don't need an intermediary JSON.

Comment: qq - If we write to the same CSV file for all the calls, does it add the headers multiple times ?

Comment: If you need CSV headers, you can write the header line before the loop.